# String for SQL Server (NetBeans)

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I am currently trying to insert Data into my T-SQL database. I have tried the code I provided below but it says:

> incorrect syntax near keyword `into`

How do I fix this line of code so it actually inserts data?

Here is my code so far (I need it in T-SQL thats why I have set identity on/off)

```
String sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON"+ "insert into APPOINTMENT"
                   +"(APPOINTMENT_ID, APPOINTMENT_DATE, VET_ID, PET_ID)"
                   +"values(?,?,?,?) SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF";
```

Comment: Please quote the error rather than describe it in your own words.

Answer (score 0):

A space after ON :

```
 String sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON "+ "insert into APPOINTMENT"
                   +"(APPOINTMENT_ID, APPOINTMENT_DATE, VET_ID, PET_ID)"
                   +"values(?,?,?,?) SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF";
```

Comment: Try `"SET IDENTITY_INSERT APPOINTMENT ON;"+ "insert into APPOINTMENT..."`.

Answer (score 0):

set identity insert --you need run another witout your query

for example

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T1 ( column_1 int IDENTITY, column_2 VARCHAR(30));  
GO  
INSERT T1 VALUES ('Row #1');  
INSERT T1 (column_2) VALUES ('Row #2');  
GO  
SET IDENTITY_INSERT T1 ON;  
GO  
INSERT INTO T1 (column_1,column_2)   
    VALUES (-99, 'Explicit identity value');  
GO  
SELECT column_1, column_2  
FROM T1;  
GO
```

in this example was run identity insert without you insert query

Answer (score 0):

Two problems with your code. You need to separate the command with whitespace and/or a semicolon statement terminator. Also, you need to specify the IDENTITY_INSERT` table name:

```
String sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT APPOINTMENT ON;"+ "INSERT INTO APPOINTMENT"
                   +"(APPOINTMENT_ID, APPOINTMENT_DATE, VET_ID, PET_ID)"
                   +"values(?,?,?,?);SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF";
```